# Simple Call Back Function not working as intended

Tags: jquery, callback

I have a simple problem, but can't seem to work it out.

This code works fine, first action is alerted before second action:

```js
// define our function with the callback argument
function some_function(callback) {
  var firstaction = alert('first action');
  // call the callback
  callback(firstaction);
}
// call the function
some_function(function(secondaction) {
  // this anonymous function will run when the
  // callback is called
  alert('second action');
});
```

```css
.background {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.border {
  border: 4px solid #ffb300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background">Test</div>
```

This almost identical piece of code does not work, no class is added and no alert is made:

```js
// define our function with the callback argument
function some_function(callback) {
  var firstaction = $(".background").addClass("border");
  // call the callback
  callback(firstaction);
}
// call the function
some_function(function(secondaction) {
  // callback is called
  alert('second action');
});
```

```css
.background {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.border {
  border: 4px solid #ffb300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background">Test</div>
```

I know that the code does not make a lot of sense otherwise but I am trying to wrap my head around why it just wouldn't add the class first and then send out an alert.

A tip of any sort would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you check in the console if there is any error? Are sure jQuery is defined?

Comment: Given the code in your original question (which I converted to snippets), you haven't included jQuery. You can now see the `$ is undefined` error more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not added jQuery in your second snippet. I modified it and included jQuery. It is now working fine.

```js
// define our function with the callback argument
function some_function(callback) {
  var firstaction = $(".background").addClass("border");
  // call the callback
  callback(firstaction);
}
// call the function
some_function(function(secondaction) {
  // callback is called
  alert('second action');
});
```

```css
.background {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.border {
  border: 4px solid #ffb300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background">Test</div>
```

Comment: I'll have a look. Thanks!

Comment: It is strange, the code that you established, I already had it like that and tried it out in the wc3schools editor. It doesn't work. In the jsfiddle.net editor, it works.

Comment: should be marcked now

Answer (score 0):

I assume that defining Jquery is the same as including Jquery.

I did so now by adding

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I also changed a small thing in my code, I started with function() {} after var. Now the second alert is coming, however class 'border' is not added.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.background {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.border {
    border: 4px solid #ffb300;
}


</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
// define our function with the callback argument
function some_function(callback) {
  var firstaction = function() {
    $(".background").addClass("border");
  };
  // call the callback
  callback(firstaction);
}
// call the function
some_function(function(secondaction) {
  // this anonymous function will run when the
  // callback is called
  alert('second action');
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="background">Test</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function "firstaction" in callback(). Try using the following snippet.

```js
// define our function with the callback argument
function some_function(callback) {
  var firstaction = function() {
    $(".background").addClass("border");
  };
  // call the callback
  callback(firstaction());
}
// call the function
some_function(function(secondaction) {
  // this anonymous function will run when the
  // callback is called
  alert('second action');
});
```

```css
.background {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.border {
  border: 4px solid #ffb300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background">Test</div>
```